# ggplot2 split color or adjacent histograms according to data

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I create a histogram where the bins are different colors above vs. below an arbitrary value, without needing to refer to the environment outside of ggplot()? For example, like this (but without needing to refer to the external variable `value.median`):

```
value = stats::rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)

df = data.frame(value) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(above.median = value > median(value))

value.median = median(value)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = above.median)) +
  geom_histogram(boundary = value.median, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

not like this (overlapping bin):

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = above.median)) +
  geom_histogram(boundary = 0, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

value = stats::rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)

#df = data.frame(value) %>%
#  dplyr::mutate(above.median = value > median(value))

df = data.frame(value)

df %>%
  {ggplot(data = ., aes(x = value, fill = ifelse(value > median(value), "0", "1"))) +
  geom_histogram(boundary = median(.$value), alpha = 0.5, position = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")}
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't achieve the core goal, which is that the two colors don't have any overlapping bins.

Comment: Ahh - sorry - I understand the problem. So adding `+ facet_wrap(~above.median, scales = "free")` wouldn't solve the issue, because you want value of 0 to be NULL?

Comment: I'm not sure about wanting the value of 0 to be NULL, but `+ facet_wrap(~above.median, scales = "free")` doesn't achieve what I'm after. It puts the histograms on different axes.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Do you have any idea why this stops working when I split the data by a grouping variable and then add facets?

Comment: Not sure sorry @Evan, I need more details. If you update your question with your 'problematic' code and tag me in a comment I can take a look, or you could post a new question.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75745359/ggplot2-split-color-histograms-according-to-data-facet-grid